# Is calling [self release] allowed to control object lifetime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create an object in Objective C but I don't hold a reference to it.

Is it allowed to let the object control its own lifetime by calling [self release]?

In case you're wondering why I need this: I want to create an object that subscribes to some notifications, but after a while the object is no longer needed and should go away.

So, is the following allowed?

```
- (void) destroyMyself {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

   [self release];
}
```

Comment: I've never used Cocoa but from what i randomly read on the web release just decrement an internal counter that the runtime garbage collector use to know when to collect the object, so this could be allowed, even if it seems strange. Again, i could totally be wrong since that's just a supposition i make from what i read some times ago.

Comment: In a reference-counting environment, there's no garbage collector, so the object is immediately released when the reference count reaches zero. (after the call to [self release], the object is effectively gone and deallocated)

Comment: Perfectly valid.  It is the beginnings of an "invalidation pattern".  What you should probably also do is set some instance variable to YES in -init and NO in -destroyMyself.  That way, you can assert that the flag is YES in other methods;  if NO, you know that your object was being used after you specifically intended it to no longer be valid.

Comment: Another example you might be tempted to use this with is an object that comprises an instance of NSTimer and a random unsigned integer (the number of times you want the timer to fire). If no other object can know about this random integer and lays claim to this wrapped timer, the timer-object can invalidate its timer and then release itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules are simple.  You should only release an object if you own it. i.e. the object was obtained with a method starting "new" or "alloc" or a method containing copy.

[Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

An object must not therefore do [self release] or [self autorelease] unless it has previously done [self retain].

Comment: Hmm, except that Apple's Objective-C programming guide says that init can call [self release] on failure: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13

Comment: Yes, but my answer (below) obey this rules. The code that creates the object can also immediately release it, meanwhile, the object that wants to hold itself in memory (i.e. a url loader) can retain itself, and later on release itself, thereby not breaking this rule.

Answer (score 18):

If you see this in code, its probably wrong. However there are legitimate response for it in certain circumstances that are arguably defensible. (So make sure you are doing it for the right reasons.)

A good example of when this makes sense, is when you create an object that goes off to download a url. The object sits in memory while downloading the url, then sends a message to its delegate saying the data is ready (or url couldn't be downloaded). Once its message has been sent it destroys itself as its no longer needed. In this situation the code/function that created the 'url downloader' may no longer even be in memory, i.e. if it was called in response to a user selection a menu item or an action in a view controller that is no longer on the screen.

This is useful when the code that creates the "download" object doesn't care if the download completes or not.

Comment: Can't your delegate also do something like `[sender release]`, instead of the sender doing `[self release]`?

Comment: I used to do this do. Then came ARC. This way of working does not play along very well with ARC.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do it that ARC does not complain.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the great philosopher Alicia Silverstone, "[I had an overwhelming sense of ickiness](http://www.quotegeek.com/index.php?action=viewcategory&categoryid=662)" when I read that. But I couldn't really tell you why.

I think I would use `autorelease` rather than a simple `release` since you're still executing code in `self` when you call it, but other than that I can't think of any technical reasons why it wouldn't work.

Comment: That, or: [self release]; self = nil;

Answer (score 3):

It's legal, but be careful.  You want to be *sure* nothing else is going to send you a message after you release yourself.

I've done this kind of thing for a faulting scheme back before we had CoreData.

Answer (score 3):

Well part of the protocol is that if you send release to self, then you should have sent retain once as well, which I suppose *you* do. Then there is nothing fishy. I mean the allocing code *must* be able to control the lifetime of your instance; it itself can only prolong its life, never make it shorter (since making it shorter, then you'd suddenly leave the allocing owner of the instance with an invalid pointer).

Comment: Are you saying I should call [self retain] in the init method?

Comment: basically yes. Perhaps you should make users of the class use an autorelease method like [ListenerClass listenerWithParam:param] since the user might as well not retain it. But requiring the class' release match up by a call to alloc/retain by the class user is *broken*

Comment: No, you shouldn't send -retain to self, because you already have a non-zero retain count after +alloc.  Always balance your retains and releases.  If you send +alloc, +new, -copy or -retain, balance them with -release or -autorelease.

Comment: NSResponder: That is exactly the point. If he wants an *internal* release call, he *has to* send retain once as well.

Comment: NSResponder: An instance could obviously not instantiate itself, so a user must send alloc + init to it; and *has to* send release or autorelease later on. So the +alloc message is *not for the class implementor* to balance

Comment: I want the class to extend its own life, so I have no other choice than to call retain on self. (because the creator of the object could release the object, which - according to best practices - it should)

Comment: In the case you describe, I would follow the example of NSTimer, where the user of your class would obtain an instance using a  convenience method.  NSTimer instances destroy themselves when they get an -invalidate message.

Comment: Hmm, except that Apple's Objective-C programming guide says that init can call [self release] on failure: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13

Answer (score 2):

And I will use [self autorelease] instead of [self release]. Because usually it's called in

```
- (void)aMethod
{
    [self.delegate aDelegateMethod:self];
    [self release];

//If you add code related to self here, after [self release], you are making a huge mistake.
}
```

If I use [self autorelease], I can still do something after autorelease.