# What is meant by [self release] in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, release

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is calling [self release] allowed to control object lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385433/is-calling-self-release-allowed-to-control-object-lifetime)

What will happen if I use this code snippet?

```
[self release]
```

Answer (score 6):

`self` descrements its own retain count by one, just like `release` would do with any other object.

The **only situation** however that I have so far come across, **where such a call was appropriate**, was the case where an **`init…` method would fail and be expected to return nil and deallocate the just allocated instance**.

In 9 out of 10 situations you shouldn't use `[self release]`, I'd estimate.

Something like this (which basically forbids the calling of `- (id)init;`, for cases where you want to force the use of a particular `- (id)initWith…` method.):

```
- (id)init {
    [self release];
    NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is not a valid initializer for the class %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                   reason:reason
                                 userInfo:nil];
    return nil;
}
```

or this (which basically enforces the proving of an object on initialization)

```
- (id)initWithFoo:(Foo *)foo {
    if (!foo) {//foo is required to be non-nil!
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }
    //proceed with initialization
    return self;
}
```

These however are not the **only** ever occasions where `[self release]` would be appropriate. But merely the ones I've come across so far. <sup>*(as **Oliver** correctly pointed out)*</sup>

Edit: Self-invalidating `NSTimer`s would probably be another (quite common, yet somewhat special) situation.

Comment: there are many other situations in which you may want to do that. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**You will release yourself**, what means that the object declares itself that it does not have to still live. If no one else retains tha object, it dies and its memory is freed

**You have little reasons to do that**, **except** if you want to create object that are not controlled by anyone else and are self controlled.
I mean, for example, **there is the case where you may want to create an self living object** that makes some treatments, and suicide when it has finished without having to tell anyone else it has finished.

Let's imagine for example a class whose purpose is just to send a message to a server :

You instanciate the class, as soon as it is istanciated it send a message to a server, it waits for the server answer, and if the answer is ok, it suicide. That way, you don't have to manage any server answer from within another class controller whose purpose is not to manage such events.

Answer (score 1):

It just decrements the receiver’s reference count.