# Are these statements correct in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Is it ok to call these statements?

```
[self release];

[super release];

[AClass release];
```

Comment: AClass is a class name itself and not a class instance. [AClass release] is not causing any compiler error or warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self release]
```

is actually encouraged when an object initialization fails. That's the main reason behind the:

```
if (self = [super init])
```

or

```
self = [super init];
if (self)
```

on the other hand

```
[AClass release]
```

seems to invoke the instance of the metaclass, which has no effect at all.

Thanks Josh Caswell for pointing my mistake out.

Finally

```
[super release]
```

should work exactly like

```
[self release]
```

since both will call NSObject's release method.

Comment: A class object is in fact an instance of its metaclass, which adopts the `NSObject` protocol (where `release` is declared); that's a valid statement, though meaningless (they are also immortal).

Comment: You're right. I thought that calling release on the class would try to invoke the class method instead of that instance's.

Answer (score 1):

Refer:
[Is calling [self release] allowed to control object lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385433/is-calling-self-release-allowed-to-control-object-lifetime) 
For the first two.

The last one is not valid. (I am assuming that aClass is a Class and not an object

Comment: `[AClass release]` is valid; a class object is itself an instance of its metaclass.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Listings/GeocoderDemo_ForwardViewController_m.html) that contains `[super release]`.

And there is [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html) that includes code examples that contain `[self release]`.

Those constructs may be useful when object initialization does not succeed.

The third formulation (`[AClass release]`) you ask about seems like it would cause an error, though.