# Is it good approach to use [self release], [self retain]?

Tags: ios, memory-management

I created DownloadAndParseBook class. It will not autorelesed before it gеt any data or network error.

I used [self release], [self retain].  Is it good approach to use [self release], [self retain]? Is DownloadAndParseBook contain any potential bugs?

```
@implementation GetBooks

-(void) books
{ 
 for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
 {
   DownloadAndParseBook *downloadAndParseBook =
        [[[DownloadAndParseBook alloc] init]autorelease];
   [downloadAndParseBook startLoadingBook];
 }
}
@end


@implementation DownloadAndParseBook

- (id)initWithAbook:(int)bookID 
{
 if(self = [super init])
 { 
    [self retain];        
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)startLoadingBook
{
 [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [self release];    
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 [self saveResultToDatabase];
 [self release];
}


@end
```

Comment: No never use `[self release]` if you can help it.

Comment: Yea, '[self release]' is a crash waiting to happen. Release from the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self retaining is very occasionally an appropriate pattern. It's rare, but sometimes in certain kinds of multi-threaded code its important to make sure that you don't vanish in the middle of processing something. That said, this is not one of those times. I'm having trouble imagining a case where your current approach would be helpful. If someone creates your object and then never calls `startLoadingBook`, then it leaks. If someone calls `startLoadingBook`, then your object is retained anyway, because `NSURLConnection` retains its delegate until it finishes.

That said, I believe much of your problem is coming from the fact that your object model is wrong. Neither `GetBooks` nor `DownloadAndParseBook` make sense as classes. What you likely mean is `BookManager` (something to hold all the books) and `BookDownloadController` (something to manage the downloading of a single book). The `BookManager` should keep track of all the current `BookDownloadControllers` (in an `NSSet` or `NSArray` ivar). Each `BookDownloadController` should keep track of its `NSURLConnection` (in an ivar). You should not just create connections and have them "hang on themselves" (i.e. self-retain). This feels convenient, but it makes the code very hard to deal with later. You have no way to control how many connections you're making. You have no way to cancel connections. It becomes a mess really quickly.

Comment: thank you. I don't want to violate any good patterns so I need to change my object model. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a best practice. 
Retaining / releasing your object should be done by the "owner" of your object. 
For your particular example, the owner of your DownloadAndParseBook object is the object that does the alloc/init. That should be the oen retaining/releasing your DownloadAndParseBook instance. 
Best practice here would be alloc/init for DownloadAndParseBook, retain done by the owner, all your download/parse logic, then sending a callback to the owner that all the operations are done (through a delegate for example), at which point, the ower sends a release message to your object.

Answer (score 0):

The question would be: Why does an object require to retain itself? You may want to implement your class like a singleton.

Comment: you may want to post comment as comments and not as answers

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other responders I would say that your pattern might work. See also [Is calling [self release] allowed to control object lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385433/is-calling-self-release-allowed-to-control-object-lifetime)

There are some other issues in your code however:

- In `-(void) books` I guess you want to send the `startLoadingBook` message to `downloadAndParseBook` and not to `self`
- If you create a `initWithAbook` method it will not be called when you init your book with the standard `init` method. In the current code above `[self retain]` will be never called
- In your code above `bookID` will not be saved
- I would not use "init" pattern here, but everything in a static function thus the caller can not make mistake with the ownership of the class.

Code:

```
- (id) initWithId:(int)bookId {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // save bookId here
  }
  return self;
}

+ (void) startLoadingBookWithID:(int)bookId {
  DownloadAndParseBook* book = [[DownloadAndParseBook alloc] initWithId:bookId];
  [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:book];
}

// release self when it finished the operation 
// and document well that its behaviour
```

If you think well, `NSURLConnection` itself should work exactly the same way: when you don't release an `NSURLConnection` when it finished its work, it does it itself. However in the `connectionWithRequest` it also can not autorelease itself since it has to be alive until the request is served. So the only way it can work is the pattern described above

Comment: I d exactly this. when my connection delegate has been called and everything has been done I call [self release] otherwise you need to keep a pointer in your other class from where you asked to launch a connection and it's heavy. But im just thinking you could actually send self to the delegate who could then release it

Answer (score 0):

Never use `[self release]`.  The only possible exception would be in an singleton class/object.  The methods `release` and `retain` should only be sent by the owner of an object.  This usually means, whichever object created the object in question, should also be the one to release it.